# Is there a way to sort a nested object using reduce/sort in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, ecmascript-6, reduce

So for a little context, my object is

```
const obj: {[key: string]: any} = {
        "1000": {
            "time": "2022-05-14T10:00:00:000Z",
            "availableSlots": 0,
            "availability": false
        },
        "1400": {
            "time": "2022-05-14T14:00:00:000Z",
            "availableSlots": 4,
            "availability": true
        },
        "0800": {
            "time": "2022-05-14T08:00:00:000Z",
            "availableSlots": 3,
            "availability": true
        },
        "0830": {
            "time": "2022-05-14T08:30:00:000Z",
            "availableSlots": 2,
            "availability": true
        }
    }
```

and I want my object sorted by the key. When I sort my Object entries, I'm able to sort them by keys by using

```
const x = Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b): number => {
    if (parseInt(a[0]) > parseInt(b[0])) { 
        return 1 
    } return -1
})
```

But when I try to reduce it to make it into an object again, it's not sorted again

```
const x = Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b): number => {
    if (parseInt(a[0]) > parseInt(b[0])) { 
        return 1 
    } return -1
}).reduce((prev, [hour, hourInfo]) => ({ ...prev, [hour]: hourInfo }), {})
```

Online Compiler of the problem: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDA3gbQNYFMCeq0ATgJZgDmAuqgIZh4C+MAvOgFAydecBEAjAAYhPVGg7cJvKCQC2OETB4AmAUqUBaAQFZ1fACwAVQciEmBZgQC0eAGnGTuPGgDcaJADY147nAGV3IFAQCgJ2DhJOrh5eHiRQeAoAZjTuEDj2EgxhDvx6wqIZ4TzScgrKqhrauob6ZnVCVraFOS5unt5+AUEKetnhvK3R8LHxClBEAK7p4VnNvAIAHPns-VzFsvKo5WqaOvoGi-XmDdZ9-ZFtXj7+gcGoAMxnRYPtIwmo41NzMLNFi-cCBRiVZSDZlFQ7Kr7Q4Ao6NJ4tKLta5dO4wJQIyQXIZvMaTaYOBgZIlsUCQWAADxYMAA8kgcMAoAA6HBgcYkHAQAAUCEQAEomRAQEQoFyuTQbPA+agwBMZPAcEQWAA+FZcEiJGBcgAONCIaQAkmzxRgBJQ+TBVbr9TgjaL4KbzRa0DBvkQcFAJkQwDA+K7uEx3Z7vTBdGwGAL3QATCbAHBi7Xu5w2GAYAAWIC9KYzXqNiRA5pVWpdTNLiZwydTOaI1Bg1bzIB+fJTaAjbHbZKFPiZAXIXLQFIjQA)

I'll compare times with the time field using *dayjs* but for the online compiler I used the keys for an easier comparison

Comment: Objects can't really be sorted, though?

Comment: @kellys read the link I posted. They can. To an extent. Not this object, however.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) and [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219)